# Need help adding rows to cross-reference table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relational-database, database-normalization

I'm writing a recipe script (php/mysql) for my kitchen app, using these tables:

```
ingredients
-----------
ingredient_id (PK)
ingredient_name
```

*(An ingredient can be part of many recipes)*

```
recipes
-------
recipe_id (PK)
recipe_name
```

*(A recipe can have many ingredients)*

```
recipe_ingredients_map
---------------------
recipe_id_map (FK)
ingredient_id_map (FK)
```

When adding a new recipe, I'll need to insert a row into the recipe_ingredients_map table for each ingredient in the recipe.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to write the query for all of this.  Save me, please?  =P

Comment: insert into recipe_ingredients_map .... (fill in the blank)

Comment: @Dagon so i would just need to store the ingredients selected into an array, and then do a standard insert?

Comment: @phgdanny - how are you writing things to the ingredients or recipe tables? It's really no different to that.

Comment: @andrewsi i haven't tried anything, since i don't know how to go about it lol.  when i saw Dagon's simple answer, it was the first time i thought about using an array.  so it really is that simple?  lol good to know!

Comment: @phgdanny as opposed to a non standard insert ?

Comment: @phgdanny - http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to write a insert query for all 3 tables.

- First insert a recipe.
- Next insert some ingredients.
- Finally link then together in in the recipe_ingredients_map.

Your recipe_ingredients_map is missing a primary key.

If it is desired you can wrap it all up in a transaction.

Comment: can you explain the primary key element to the "mapping" table?  i'm new to the concept of normalization, and thought all i would need would be foreign keys linked to the others.

Comment: Every table must have a PK, otherwise there is no way to identify a row. Add a extra field and name it recipe_ingredients_map_id